# Unable to set configuration variable in SparkConf

Tags: apache-spark

**Background**:

Iam currently using Spark Lineage information about all the operations happening around. I have a transformation which has more than 35 fields and I need to log the same. However In Spark the default you can log 25 fields as per Spark [Code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/363af16c72abe19fc5cc5b5bdf9d8dc34975f2ba/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L1975). This could be overwritten by setting

```
spark.debug.maxToStringFields
```

So here is how I do the same

**Code**

```scala
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().set("spark.debug.maxToStringFields","100")
                               .setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("My App")
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().conf(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
```

However the property doesnt seem to be setting in the spark session.

**DEBUG**

```scala
val allConfs = sparkSession.sparkContext.getConf
allConfs.foreach(conf =>println(conf._1+" value "+conf._2))
```

Here iam unable to see the property that I have set. Also I still get the error/message that spark gives when the default length is 25

What am i missing here?

Comment: What's your spark version?

Comment: I wonder if it's this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264668/spark-debug-maxtostringfields-spark-sql-debug-maxtostringfields-relation

Comment: @mck Current version is 2.4

Comment: then try using `spark.debug.maxToStringFields` instead?

Comment: Sorry My bad!! Had  used spark.debug.maxToStringFields itself. Editing the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`spark.debug.maxToStringFields\` & \`spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields\` relation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264668/spark-debug-maxtostringfields-spark-sql-debug-maxtostringfields-relation)